# Remove "Last login" message for new tabs in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

After some search about it I created a `~/.hushlogin` file and it worked, but only for new windows. Is there a way to make it work for new tabs too?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Solution

This is running OS X 10.8.3. I haven't tested it on other versions, but so long as Terminal has the above option, then it should work.

1. In Terminal.app, go to Preferences->Settings and select the profile you're using. Go to the 'Shell' tab and under the 'Startup' heading, check 'Run command:' and enter into the box:

   ```
   login -fpql your-username /bin/bash
   ```

   Substitute `your-username` with your actual Unix username. If you use a shell other than the default bash shell, replace `/bin/bash` with the full path to that shell (yes, even if you've already set it in Preferences->Startup.)
2. Make sure 'Run inside shell' is **unchecked**.
3. If you have the "Prompt before closing: Only if there are processes other than login shell and:" option selected, add "login" and "bash" to the list of processes it will not prompt for.
4. Make sure you have a `~/.bashrc` file, since this will be the file bash uses on startup from now on rather than `~/.bash_profile`. I just have one file reference the other using [this method](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html). You also need to be sure it sources /etc/profile.

### Explanation

We want to run `login` with the `-q` option to tell it to supress the "Last login" message, even in the absence of a `.hushlogin` file. (As noted above, `login` will only look in cwd for that file, not your home directory, so you'd need a `.hushlogin` file in every directory you'd open a shell to, for that method to work.)

The problem is Terminal runs something like `login -pfl your-username /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /usr/local/bin/bash` when you create a new shell (I'm using homebrew's version of bash, hence the weird bash path at the end,) which lacks the `-q` flag.

Unfortunately, there's no way to directly change the arguments Terminal uses, so we just trampoline a new login session with `login -pfql` from Terminal's default `login -pfl` session. Inelegant, but it works.

We need to have the `-q` option and the path to bash to keep the "New windows/tabs open with: Same Working Directory" option working. If you don't care about that option, you can remove that flag and argument, and probably avoid the `.bashrc` stuff above.

Comment: thanks! it works like a charm! the only drawback is that new tabs don't keep the same cwd...

Comment: I don't want to abuse, but is there any way to keep the same working directory on new tabs?

Comment: This method should preserve your cwd; hence the use of the -l option and running /bin/bash after login. Is it not working for you?did the old (noisy) shell preserve it?

Comment: nope... always opens my home dir, if I rollback those changes or use another profile that works fine.

Comment: What is the result of running `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` and `echo "$PS1"`? My guess is that you're not source /etc/profile when you start your login shell, which means you're losing the Bash configuration which sends your cwd to Terminal.app as you move around.

Comment: `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` returns nothing, just a blank line. `echo "$PS1"` returns `\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " %s") \$ ` because of [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) so I can see my current branch right on the prompt. I reverted to the original way, without using git-prompt.sh and custom PS1 but didn't help, still losing cwd.

Comment: In your ~/.bashrc, add a line `[[ -f /etc/profile ]] && . /etc/profile` at the very top. You may also want to add something like `\[\e]0;\w\a\]` to your $PS1 variable, too.

Comment: awesome! now everything is perfect! thank you very much @int3h!

Comment: Had a problem with $PATH not including some paths, but was cleanly fixed using @int3h method. Thanks!

Comment: I'd just like to add - on macOS with iTerm2, the login command can be pasted into Preferences>Profiles>General>Command, and it will execute it instead of the system default login.

Comment: This works ok, but looses folder context due to username. I wish someone could figure out how to do that without loosing functionality.

Comment: q option is not working. still opening in home directory. also, quitting leads to confirmation due to process open. also, hardcoding username is a problem for bashing i am guessing into various users account.

Comment: if this remain, meaning if tabs always open in home folder, a better approach would be to use .hushlogin

Comment: What worked best for me is `login -fpql nhooyr /bin/zsh -l`. The `-l` makes sure the shell is started as a login shell so you don't need to source anything yourself.

Answer (score 145):

On Mavericks, creating the empty file `~/.hushlogin` removes the line “Last login”, for new windows and new tabs.

On my Mac it works.

Comment: The problem is that when opening a new tab with "Same Working Directory" enabled, the current directory is searched for `.hushlogin`. Unless you put a `.hushlogin` in every single directory, it will only see `~/.hushlogin` if you open a new tab when you're in `~`. This is in direct conflict with the feature of preserving the current working directory.

Comment: @gibatronic — It works always for a new window. It works for a new tab if I am in `~`. Alas, it does not work for a new tab if I am not in `~`.

Comment: yep... that's why I ended up doing what [int3h](http://stackoverflow.com/users/577440) said in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16181082/791414)

Comment: It does *not* work under Yosemite (for me). Open a new tab in a folder different than `~` and you will see that.

Comment: Works perfect for MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Works on Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Works 5/10 new tabs. Not reliable.

Comment: Seems to only work if you are in home folder when new tabbing.

Answer (score 17):

you could just add a `clear` to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: it's a good alternative, but I don't like how `clear` just prints new lines to "clear" the screen.

Answer (score 17):

Adding `~/.hushlogin` is fine unless you want to open a new tab in the same folder, or open Terminal from Finder on the exact folder, in that case it won't work.

Changing a running command to another login is something I would like to avoid because of the strange unnecessary scheme `login -> login -> zsh`. You can see it in Activity Monitor, but also it will show up when you are quitting interactive programs (like, python repl) in the message that python, login and zsh are running.

Putting `clear` in `~/.zshrc` is not ideal since on mac it just prints a lot of newlines (and if you scroll back, you'll see them).

The best way that I found up to this point is adding `printf '\33c\e[3J'` to `~/.zshrc` (or in `Terminal/Preferences/Profiles/Shell/Startup/Run command` with `Run inside shell` checked). I chose beginning of `~/.zshrc` file since startup command is running after it and if the `~/.zshrc` file is heavy you can briefly see Last Login message before printf is executed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022.

Comment: I still see a flash of the logged history message (and a message from my company about the computer being their property) for a split second, but then it disappears and looks fine. It's too bad there's no way to make it treat it as if there was a .hushlogin file in every directory.

Comment: If using iTerm2, you can add this command to your terminal profile under the general tab > `Send text at start`.

Answer (score 7):

This might be OS version dependent.  On Terminal 2.3 (on 10.8), touching the file `~/.hushlogin` suppresses the 'last login' message for new tabs as well as new windows.  That is, it Works For Me.

Just in case it helps to work out what's going on (and in case you don't know), note that the 'last login' message is in principle coming from `login`(1), and not the shell.  Or, more precisely, if a shell is invoked in a particular way (including starting it with the `-l` option), then bash will "act as if it had been invoked as a login shell" (zsh may have a similar feature, though I can't find it right now).  Now, it *could* be that when Terminanl opens up a new tab in your OS X version, the shell is effectively *simulating* opening a login shell, and maybe getting this detail wrong.  But if you have the 10.8 version of bash/zsh (namely 3.2.48 / 4.3.11), then I don't know what might be amiss.

Comment: that's a good theory, indeed my bash is 3.2.48 (OS X 10.8.3). thanks for your time! but it was a more naïve issue... I just needed to restart my computer!

Comment: That's odd (I wouldn't have thought a restart would have had any effect).  Have a look at the output of `ps aux|grep yourusername|grep -v /` (replacing `yourusername` obviously!).  I see a number of lines `login -pf myusername` each with a matching `-zsh` process.  The `-` preceding the `zsh` is indicating that the shell is being invoked as a login shell (zsh is the shell I use, but you should see something very similar if you use bash).  If the zsh/bash lines don't have a leading `-`, then they're not (acting as) login shells.  This should just work – I'm rather perplexed.

Comment: running that command I got one `login -pf` and two `-bash` processes

Comment: uhmm... I found what seems to be the problem, whenever I open a new tab from a different directory than my home folder `~` I get the login message, it seems that the terminal always look for `.hushlogin` on the current directory! that's why it only works for new windows for me, new windows always open at `~`!

Comment: Aha: that sounds plausible.  Check your Terminal preferences, then – there's a setting 'New tabs open with...', and there you can set 'Default working directory'.

Comment: that's a shame though, it's really handy for me that new tabs keep the same working directory... it would be good some sort of global hushlogin! do you know anything like it @NormanGray?

Comment: Come to think of it, I think that's an OS X bug.  The login(1) manpage says "If the file .hushlogin exists in the user's home directory, all of these messages are suppressed" so it shouldn't be dependent on where the new tab is opened.  Do you want to report it or shall I?

Comment: please, feel free to report!

Comment: Oh: the 'new tabs open with default working directory' setting doesn't seem to work for me.  Too weird – I give up!

Comment: it's really weird, new tabs seems to open in a different way than new windows!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I don't think ones thing has been resolved in other answers. If you want to not show the login but want to have a welcome message from `/etc/motd` appear, then you can do one of the following.

In the first method start by

```bash
cd ~
touch .hushlogin
```

Then you can add `cat /etc/motd` to the top of either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` depending on which shell you use.

The second approach is to add

```bash
clear
cat /etc/motd
```

to the first two lines of either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` depending on which shell you use.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution *without changing anything related to login* would be just to add the `clear` command in the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file. It will clear the terminal in initialization from any initialization prints. It works for me very well.